# Align bullet in NSAttributedString with UITextView

Tags: html, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

i have a problem aligning text within a bullet in html. I use `NSAttributedString` inside `UITextView`

```
var htmlAttributedString: NSAttributedString {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
    do{
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    }catch{
        return NSAttributedString()
    }
}

var htmlToString: String {
    return htmlAttributedString.string
}
```

I set `UITextView`'s text with `mystring.htmlToString` but this is what I got

[image: bullet]

I want to align my list into this kind of unordered list that has no overflow in 2nd line.

- lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
- lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
- lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438043/nsattributedstring-and-html-styling-bullet-alignment), but still has no asnwer. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Tableview ?? will helpful for this ?

Comment: @McDonal_11what do you mean by tableview?

Comment: What's your html string (with lorem ipsum, that's okay)? Is it really the same one as the linked question?