# HTML Bullet point sin NSAttributedString alignment

Tags: html, swift, nsattributedstring

I've tried so many of the other answers on here and none seem to work. [This one seems closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438043/nsattributedstring-and-html-styling-bullet-alignment) but the solutions haven't helped. I'm displaying the following HTML (we get this back in a response):

```
<p>Welcome blah blah</p>\n
<ul>\n
<li>Here's bullet point number one blah blah blahb blah blah</li>\n
<li>Here's bullet point number two</li>\n
<li>Bullet point number three is longer and will wrap around but look strange blah blah blah</li>\n
</ul>
```

I'm using NSAttributedString and have this in place:

```
public extension Data {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: self,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("error:", error)
            return  nil
        }
    }
    
    var htmlToString: String { htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? "" }
}

public extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        Data(utf8).htmlToAttributedString
    }
    
    var htmlToString: String {
        htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

This works fine but for text longer than the view it wraps around without an indent. Any ideas on what I can do my side?

[image]

Comment: How do you draw the string?

Comment: @Willeke I use `content.htmlToString` - content being the html in a string object

Comment: How is the image created?